# Difference between Solana pay transaction request and transfer request?

Tags: transfer, transaction, solana-pay

could anyone explain me what is difference between transaction request and transfer request . I've seen in transaction request we are sending back a transaction to customer to sign and approve .And In transfer request we are just sending an url containing the transfer rquest.

Answer (score 3):

**Not all transactions are transfers.**

In transaction request, A Transaction is created like for example minting a NFT and any possible tx on solana. This transaction is read by wallet's then they parse the transaction and ask's the user to sign it from their phones.You can better understand it's working and implementation from this docs [here](https://docs.solanapay.com/core/transaction-request/merchant-integration) and transfer request's are simply used to transfer x amount of SOL or SPL tokens from user's account to a merchant account. Transfer requests are kind of subset of Transaction requests.